# How do I know when docker pull updates an image?

Tags: bash, 18.04, scripts, docker

I have a script that I run to update images and then `stop` -> `rm` -> `run` them again. Unfortunately, the last 3 steps happen even if `pull` didn't update the image (i.e. it's already up to date). How can I change my bash script so that it only runs the last 3 commands if the pull updated the image?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

docker pull linuxserver/sonarr
docker stop sonarr
docker rm sonarr
./run-sonarr.sh

docker pull linuxserver/radarr
docker stop radarr
docker rm radarr
./run-radarr.sh

docker pull linuxserver/nzbget
docker stop nzbget
docker rm nzbget
./run-nzbget.sh

docker pull plexinc/pms-docker
docker stop plex
docker rm plex
./run-plex.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the string "Image is up to date" is *not* present:

```
...
export LANG=C
if ! docker pull linuxserver/sonarr | grep "Image is up to date"; then
    docker stop sonarr
    docker rm sonarr
    ./run-sonarr.sh
fi
...
```

Comment: This is language dependent...

Comment: Yes it is, so use LANG=C

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image IDs before and after the pull and compare them:

```
docker images --format '{{.ID}}' <your image>
```

For instance:

```
# ID of current image
~/ >docker images --format '{{.ID}}' tomcat:latest
d636936d0d85

# Pull it (updated this time)
~/ >docker pull tomcat:latest
latest: Pulling from library/tomcat
05d1a5232b46: Pull complete 
5cee356eda6b: Pull complete 
89d3385f0fd3: Pull complete 
65dd87f6620b: Pull complete 
78a183a01190: Pull complete 
1a4499c85f97: Pull complete 
2c9d39b4bfc1: Pull complete 
1b1cec2222c9: Pull complete 
fc95b85a81f3: Pull complete 
0f3868647539: Pull complete 
9b6a6eddb2d9: Pull complete 
8787183cb077: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:d789f1dc613ef36a24c29f36bdef4891907cd854a5723c73acf6ba78dfc9ac78
Status: Downloaded newer image for tomcat:latest

# ID of new image (different)
~/ >docker images --format '{{.ID}}' tomcat:latest
41a54fe1f79d

# Pull again
~/ >docker pull tomcat:latest
latest: Pulling from library/tomcat
Digest: sha256:d789f1dc613ef36a24c29f36bdef4891907cd854a5723c73acf6ba78dfc9ac78
Status: Image is up to date for tomcat:latest

# Same ID
~/ >docker images --format '{{.ID}}' tomcat:latest
41a54fe1f79d
```